# Sharepoint event receiver and document library and version is deleted

Tags: sharepoint, events, versioning, receiver

I am currently developing a Sharepoint Event Receiver project and I need to fetch the event according to when a version associated to a file is deleted. Is there any event receiver for this?

None of the following events are being fired when a version associated to a file is deleted.

- ItemDeleted
- ItemUpdated
- ItemAttachmentDeleted

Am I missing something or is this simply not supported?

Answer (score 0):

This is a list of all EventReceiver Methods http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407299.aspx

I'm afraid none of these are able to provide the functionally you are looking for. You could try using one of the synchronous methods i.e ItemDeleting

Comment: Thank you. I am afraid you are correct as I have not been able to find a way to trigger an event for this.